# Problem with using Skeleton in Alert component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to have a full width (width: 100%) Skeleton in an Alert component. But the Skeleton doesn't take up all the place.

[image]

Relevant code:

```
<Alert
  icon={<NotificationsIcon sx={{ color: "#000000B3" }} />}
  sx={{
    color: "#000000B3",
    background: "#ebebeb",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  }}
  action={
    <IconButton>
      <OpenInNewIcon sx={{ color: "#000000B3" }} />
    </IconButton>
  }
>
  <AlertTitle>
    <Skeleton variant="text" width="100%" />
  </AlertTitle>
  <Skeleton variant="text" width="100%" />
</Alert>
```

Thank you!

Edit (comment request):

I've imported the component as such:

```
import {
  Alert,
  AlertTitle,
  Skeleton,
} from "@mui/material";
```

And the parent component:

```
<ListItem disableGutters dense key={index}>
     <Alert>...</Alert>
 </ListItem>
```

Comment: You need to post how you imported `Alert` component as well as what style the wrapper component has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the wrapper within the `Alert` component has not full width.

You should update the styles for `MuiAlert-message` class name like this.

```
           <Alert
            icon={<NotificationsIcon sx={{ color: "#000000B3" }} />}
            sx={{
              color: "#000000B3",
              background: "#ebebeb",
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              '& .MuiAlert-message': {
                width: '100%'
              }
            }}
            action={
              <IconButton>
                <OpenInNewIcon sx={{ color: "#000000B3" }} />
              </IconButton>
            }
          >
            <AlertTitle>
              <Skeleton variant="text" width="100%" />
            </AlertTitle>
            <Skeleton variant="text" width="100%" />
          </Alert>
```

[image]

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs, Glad that helped!